# Can we define the notion of a Poincaré duality algebra over a ring?

Tags: algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra

A graded commutative, connected $\mathbb{k}$-algebra is called a *Poincaré duality algebra* if it is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{k}$, so that $$A = \bigoplus_{i=1}^d A^i,$$ and the $\mathbb{k}$-linear maps

$$A^i \rightarrow Hom_{\mathbb{k}}(A^{d-i},A^d), \quad a \mapsto \phi_a, \text{ where } \phi_a(b)=ab$$

are isomorphisms.

Every definition that I've seen of a Poincaré duality algebra (for example [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701309.pdf) by Stanley and Lambrechts) assumes that $\mathbb{k}$ is a field. Is this necessary? Is there a problem with simply having $\mathbb{k}$ to be a ring? E.g. $\mathbb{Z}$?

For example, it can be stated that the cohomology algebra of a manifold is a Poincaré duality algebra, but in the above definition I think that we would have to have $\mathbb{k}$ a field (or have zero torsion) in order for that map to be an isomorphism. Is this the case?